# Law of sines solving for triangles

Tags: trigonometry

Use the Law of Sines to solve for all possible triangles that satisfy the given conditions. (If an answer does not exist, enter DNE. Round your answers to one decimal place. Below, enter your answers so that ∠B1 is larger than ∠B2.)
a = 38,    c = 44,    ∠A = 35°

∠B1 =____°          ∠B2 =____°
∠C1 =____°          ∠C2 =____°
b1 =____             b2 =____

a=38, c=44, ∠A = 35° 
What I have so far: 
sin(35)/38 = sinC/44 
44sin(35) = 38sinC 
44sin(35)/38 = sinC 
sinC = 0.6641 
sin^-1(0.6641) 
∠C = 41.6º 
Is this ∠C1?

After this I don't know how to derive the rest

Comment: Could you add the source and make the question clear?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Both figures in the bottom row satisfy the given conditions. Hence, there are two sets of answers.