# trigonometry issue: can i continue solving with a negative angle?

Tags: trigonometry

i'm on  the verge of solving a basic sine equation that presented 2 sides (b,c) and 1 angle (B), i found angle C (which had two possibilities) and started solving for angle A using the two possibilities of angle C (180-(B+C1orC2)), A1 turned out a positive no. while A2 turned out negative.

should i continue solving for both angles to find a1 and a2, or should i only solve for the positive one? are negative angles considered valid for solving in this situation?

Comment: How did you get two possibilities for $C$? Given two sides and the angle those two sides make, there's only one possible triangle, so only one possible angle $C$.

Comment: I have just answered a similar question. See if this ( http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061804/law-of-sines-solving-for-triangles/1061962#1061962 ) helps.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you get two possibilities if you used the sine rule (a/sineA = c/sineC) to find C then subtract 180-C to find the other C possibility, the book i study from suggests you do that if you have 2 sides and 1 angle.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you can find such in http://mecmath.net/trig/trigbook.pdf skip to page 48 example 2.2

Comment: But how do you use $a/\sin A=c/\sin C$ when you are given neither $A$ nor $C$?.

Comment: In Example 2.2, you are given $a$, $A$, and $c$. In the question you pose here, you are given $a$, $B$, and $c$. You can't use $a/\sin A=c/\sin C$ when you are given neither $A$ nor $C$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ohh lol the question i'm answering is not the example it is a related question of the same nature, you can easily find A and C if you have B, b and c by using the rule (excuse my error) b/sinB = c/sineC

Comment: @GerryMyerson ohh lol, i didn't notice i wrote a instead of b, sorry for the confusion and thanks for paying attention ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you assume your triangles are real and eucledian (most trig courses do during entire course ) then you will not admit negative angles or imaginary lengths on sides of triangles with more or less than 180 degrees as sum of interior angles.. thus no need to pursue a negative angle